# Best inter process messaging pattern for regularly listening to several processes on the same localhost

Tags: c, design-patterns, message-queue, zeromq, d

I have a weird case that I need to create many processes from my main process.

These processes that I create will queue some messages from a web socket.

And in an interval, like every second or so, I will poll these small processes from my main process. The language I use is D and the messaging library is ZMQD ( which is just a wrapper for C zmq library ).

The minimal example I have for my main process :

```
Socket*[] socketList;

string sRecv( Socket* socket)
{
    ubyte[256] buffer;
    immutable size = socket.receive(buffer);
    import std.algorithm: min;
    return buffer[0 .. min(size,256)].idup.asString();
}

void startServer( string servername )
{
    auto pid = spawnProcess(["/home/erdem/eclipse-workspace/WebSocketDenemesi/websocketdenemesi",
                              servername, "\n"]);
    auto requester = new Socket(SocketType.req);
    auto allName = "ipc:///tmp/" ~  servername;
    requester.connect(allName);
    socketList ~= requester;

}

void main() {

    import std.array : split;
    import std.algorithm : each;

    startServer("iotabtc@depth");
    startServer("iotabtc@aggTrade");
    startServer("ethbtc@depth");

    int counter = 30;
    while(counter--) {
        foreach ( requester; socketList)
        {
            requester.send("send"); 
        }

        foreach ( requester; socketList)
        {
            auto strList = sRecv(requester).split("\n");
            strList.each!( str => writefln("Received [%d]reply [%s]", strList.length,  str) );

        }
        sleep(1000.msecs);
    }
    foreach ( requester; socketList)
    {
        requester.send("done"); 
    }
}
```

And the minimal example I have for my small processes :

```
WebSocket startSocket( string temp )
{
    auto ws_url = URL(temp);
    auto ws = connectWebSocket(ws_url);
    if ( !ws.connected )
        return null;    
    return  ws;
}

void close( WebSocket ws )
{
    int timeOut = 5;
    while ( ws && ws.connected && timeOut-- )
    {
        vibe.core.concurrency.async( { ws.close(); return true;} ); 
        sleep(5.msecs);
    }   
}

string sRecv(ref Socket socket)
{
    ubyte[256] buffer;
    immutable size = socket.tryReceive(buffer)[0];
    import std.algorithm: min;
    return size ? buffer[0 .. min(size,256)].idup.asString() : "";
}

void main( string[] args ) {

    auto responder = Socket(SocketType.rep);
    string seperatorChar = args[2];
    string temp = "ipc:///tmp/" ~ args[1];
    responder.bind(temp);

    string socketName =  "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/" ~ args[1];
    auto curSocket = startSocket(socketName);
    string curString;
    while (true) {
        auto result = responder.sRecv();
        if ( result == "send")
        {
            responder.send(curString);      
            curString = "";
        }
        else if ( result == "done" )
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            if ( curSocket.dataAvailableForRead )
            {
                auto text = curSocket.receiveText();
                if ( !curString.empty )
                   curString ~= seperatorChar;
                curString ~= text;
            }
        }
        sleep(100.msecs);
    }
    writeln( "Shutting down: ", args[1]);
    curSocket.close();

}
```

This is the first time I am using this Messaging library. That is why I am using simple **`REQ/REP`** sockets. Is there a better way to achieve my requirement. Is there a better messaging pattern for example?  For example is there a pattern in which my small processes are not blocked by **`responder.receive( buffer );`**.

If there is some, than I will not need to listen websocket from another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the ZeroMQ-based [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)

> *Is there a **better messaging pattern** for example ?*

This depends on how your processes need to communicate. In short, using **`REQ/REP` in a blocking-mode** is almost the worst option from the menu.

- given your websocket just receives an async piece of information ( which is a common way, how Markets re-broadcast the flow of events ), the pure `ws.recv()` + `PUSHer.send()` + `if PULLer.poll(): PULLer.recv()` pipelined event-acquisition + **`PUSH/PULL`** propagation + conditional re-processing would best meet the real-world behaviour.
- given your footprint of processing farm may grow beyond a single localhost, other transport-classes, for non-local nodes ~`{ tipc:// | tcp:// | udp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | norm:// | vmci:// }` might get into the game, altogether with `ipc://`-links on your current localhost - ZeroMQ transparency in handling this mix is a cool benefit of moving into mastering the Zen-of-Zero.
- given latency is critical on a massive scale of processing distribution, a **`PUB/SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Archetype Pattern may become beneficial, with an option to use `.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE, 1 )` for non-logging nodes, where just the most recent prices are relevant for taking any responsive XTO action of any sort of kind.

Comment: I have thousand questions to ask you but stack overflow is not a good platform to ask multiple questions unfortunately. Mainly is it possible for you to add a minimal example for solution with "poll" . Secondly I solved getting blocked problem by using ZMQ_NOBLOCK while recieving. Does it still considered blocking mode?

Comment: Thousands questions? Feel free to start asking one after accepting a previous one. This is how StackOverflow works. The **`REQ/REP`**'s problem is not related with using or not using the `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` flag, but with it's principally unavoidable & **unresolvable fall into a mutual deadlock** state ( the archetype uses a pair of distributed **F**inite-**S**tate-**A**utomata, with this mutual singularity, so there is no doubt about principally falling into this "black-hole", **the only question is *when***.

Comment: I update my server&client examples with working once including the websocket. Is it possible for you to comment a bit more specifically related with examples. Sorry for asking too much but is it possible for you to give suggestions to convert this into ws.recv() + PUSHer.send() + if PULLer.poll(): PULLer.recv() messaging model.